# Limiting records in a one-to-many join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to generate a list of records where the header contains a single record and the FIRST entry in the log denotes the creation date of the record.  All other detail records are unnecessary and create multiple results when I only need the first.

I've tried "group by", self joins, distinct, etc, but so far nothing I've done has the intended effect.  I feel like I'm missing something really obvious here.

This is what I'm working with:

```
SELECT i.id
    ,l.CreateDate
    ,i.departmentname
    ,i.productkey
    ,c.Description
FROM dbo.table i (NOLOCK)

JOIN dbo.log l ON i.id = l.id

JOIN dbo.LU_Table c ON i.id = c.ID

WHERE l.CreateDate > '2019-04-01'

AND l.CreateDate < '2019-04-30'
```

I would like to see:

```
ID# 1, 04/05/2019, Department, Product, Description
ID# 2, 04/05/2019, Department, Product, Description
ID# 3, 04/05/2019, Department, Product, Description
ID# 4, 04/05/2019, Department, Product, Description
```

Instead, I get:

```
ID# 1, 04/05/2019, Department, Product, Description
ID# 1, 04/06/2019, Department, Product, Description
ID# 1, 04/07/2019, Department, Product, Description
ID# 1, 04/08/2019, Department, Product, Description
ID# 1, 04/09/2019, Department, Product, Description
ID# 2, 04/05/2019, Department, Product, Description
ID# 2, 04/06/2019, Department, Product, Description
ID# 2, 04/07/2019, Department, Product, Description
ID# 2, 04/08/2019, Department, Product, Description
ID# 2, 04/09/2019, Department, Product, Description
```

Comment: Are there any one-to-many relationships between tables? And do you really have a table named *table*? If all IDs are primary keys, you might not want to `JOIN` on them but PK to FKs.

Comment: Negative on a table named table.  However, in dbo.table, there will only ever be a single instance of an ID.  In dbo.log, however, I might have 1 or I might have 100 entries that share the same ID that is in dbo.table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understood from query is that there are the table name table i has single record for id and the log table may have multiple record against each ID .

You can achieve this by creating a derived table for log table.

Derived Table

```
Select  row_number() over(partition by ID order by ID) srno     
          , ID 
          , creation_date
   From log
```

Try this

```
SELECT i.id
    ,l.CreateDate
    ,i.departmentname
    ,i.productkey
    ,c.Description
FROM dbo.table i (NOLOCK)
JOIN (Select  row_number() over(partition by ID order by ID) srno       
              , ID 
              , creation_date
       From log ) l  on l.id = i.id and  l.srno = 1

JOIN dbo.LU_Table c ON i.id = c.ID
WHERE l.CreateDate > '2019-04-01'

AND l.CreateDate < '2019-04-30'
```

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I needed.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way i think would be to put Order By after your where clause. so it would look like `ORDER BY l.CreateDate, i.id ASC` and that should do the trick.

Comment: Nope, sorry.  When I do the  order by then I just get all of my ID's sorted by createdate, but I still get as many rows for the same ID as I have log entries.

Answer (score 0):

You would seem to want:

```
SELECT i.id, l.CreateDate, i.departmentname, i.productkey, c.Description
FROM dbo.table i JOIN
     (SELECT l.id, MIN(l.CreateDate) as CreateDate
      FROM dbo.log l
      GROUP BY l.id
     ) l
     ON i.id = l.id JOIN
     dbo.LU_Table c
     ON i.id = c.ID
WHERE l.CreateDate > '2019-04-01' AND
      l.CreateDate < '2019-04-30';
```

Comment: I feel like I'm really close with this... I'm going to tweak it a bit and see if I can make it work.  Will update in a bit.